# parse a csv file by column and store in list

Tags: python, csv

I want to write a function that takes a file name, column number. This will read from a csv file and return the values of the specified column in a list. I need to replace empty spots with 0 and skip headers when they exist. I need some help to make it work. Thanks

Comment: Python has a `csv` module for this. Have a look at it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it

```
import csv

def get_column(filename, n, header=True):
    with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
        rdr = csv.reader(csvfile)
        # skip one row if header is True
        if header:
            next(rdr, None)

        # take only the rows where the field exists
        l = [ row[n] for row in rdr if len(row) > n]
    return l
```

The columns are numbered from 0, i.e. `get_column("mycsv.csv", 0)` will return the contents of column 1.

The code above just ignores all rows where there is no column `n`. If you want it to fill in a default insted, then replace the list comprehension by:

```
l = [ row[n] if len(row) > n else None for row in rdr ]
```

Of course, you may chenge the `None` into whatever you need.

The safest option is just to use:

```
l = [ row[n] for row in rdr ]
```

because it will throw an exception, if the field is missing on a row.